# Spinner onSelectedItem to string?

Tags: android, arrays, string, spinner

I have a Spinner and a separate String-Array with five numbers.

This is the String-Array:

```
<resources>
<string-array name="numbers">
    <item>10001</item>
    <item>10002</item>
    <item>10003</item>
    <item>10004</item>
    <item>10005</item>
</string-array>
```

When I select a Spinner item, I want that the selected Spinner item references to one of the numbers from the String-Array.

Example:

Spinner selected item is "Bob" and his number is 10002.
I want to get the Spinner selection to a String, so I can use it further.

Further usage for that String:

```
String phoneNo = *number from the String-Array*


                try {
                    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, message, null, null);
```

Comment: Add the code you have now.  How is Bob related to the number? Is it in an object somewhere?

Comment: Bob is it's in own String-Array that is used for a Spinner. And I need to relate Bob to his number. Number is in a separate String-Array.

Answer (score 0):

If the string array that contains Bob is the same size as the string array that contains Bob's number, you could organize both string arrays such that the index of Bob's name is the same as the index for his number.

That way, you would just use one index to reference related elements in both string arrays.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably best to make some sort of mapping, then retrieve the number from the map with the `OnItemSelectedListener`. Sic

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity 
    implements OItemSelectedListener
{
    ...
    private Map<Integer, String> mNumbers;
    ...
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        mNumbers = new HashMap<>();
        String[] numbers = getResources().getStringArray(R.id.numbers);
        String[] name = getResources().getStringArray(R.id.names);

        if (names.length == numbers.length) {
            for (i = 0; i < names.length; i++) mNumbers.put(i + 1 /*I think*/, numbers[i];
        } else { Log.wtf("YourActivity", "somehow names and numbers are different sizes"); }
        ...
        //btw: you're going to want a better storage option.
        Spinner yourSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(...);
        yourSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }
    ...
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
         String number = mNumbers.get(position); //I cant remember if the position is zero or one indexed
         //do your thing
    }
```